# GPU programming in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, gpu

I have an ATI graphics card in my laptop running Ubuntu 10.10. I installed the OpenCL library and tried to run programs in the GPU through Mathematica.

I imported the package "[OpenCLLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/OpenCLLink/tutorial/Overview.html)" and checked [OpenCLQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/OpenCLLink/ref/OpenCLQ.html)[] and it returned `True`
but when I run the example from the introduction in Mathematica it doesn't work. All the program is supposed to do is double a vector. For example, with `doubleFun[{1,2,3},3]` the output should be {2,4,6}, but in my case the output is still the same: {1,2,3}.

What might be the cause of this problem? Is it a configuration issue or something else?

Comment: Could you please post the address of the reference page, or the guide page you ran examples off of. This can be found in the address bar in Mathematica's help browser. An example of an address is `OpenCLLink/ref/OpenCLFunctionLoad`

Comment: @Sasha I assume it is OpenCLLink/tutorial/Introduction

Comment: @It's not the example itself. That works for me, so it must be something else. Are you sure you didn't modify the function code?

Comment: sorry for late .. 

the example is in OpenCLLink/tutorial/Introduction like Sjoerd said .. :)

the doublefun example ..